# Issues with CollectionViewControllerCell not Showing up CollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm making an iPhone app using Firebase and I'm having a small issue with the following code.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ChatController: UICollectionViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var game: Game? {
        didSet {
            navigationItem.title = game?.name
        }
    }

    lazy var inputTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "Enter message..."
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textField
    }()

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.register(ChatMessageCell.self,  forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        setupInputComponents()
    }

    var messages = [Message]()

    func observeMessages() {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("games").child((game?.id)!).child("messages")
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let message = Message()
                message.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.messages.append(message)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return messages.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

//        let message = messages[indexPath.item]
//        cell.textView.text = message.text
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 80)
    }

    // Sets up the entire message sending
    // container for the send button and input
    // text field
        func setupInputComponents() {
        // Creates the container for send button
        // and input text field
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(containerView)

        // anchor constraints and x,y,w,h
        // for positioning the container
        containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        // Creates the send button
        let sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
        sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)
        containerView.addSubview(sendButton)

        // Positions the send button within the container
        sendButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        sendButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        // Creates the input text field
        containerView.addSubview(inputTextField)

        // Positions the send button within the container
        inputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        inputTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        inputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        inputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        // Create a seperator for this component
        let seperatorLineView = UIView()
        seperatorLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
        seperatorLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(seperatorLineView)

        // Positions the seperator
        seperatorLineView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        seperatorLineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        seperatorLineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        seperatorLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    @objc func handleSend() {

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("games").child("-L6lIJt_cw6saNNWMgu1").child("messages")
        ref.keepSynced(true)
        let childRef =  ref.childByAutoId()
        let values = ["text": inputTextField.text!]
        childRef.updateChildValues(values)
    }
}
```

I have some commented out pieces which are actually what I'm wanting to display as text in my cells but I can't even get the colored boxes to show up for me inside the CollectionViewController. The DB retrieval code works perfectly fine and I can display what it gives me in a TableViewController. It's just not in the CollectionViewController that I've made here.

What is happening exactly is that the application builds and loads successfully, but when I navigate to this screen, the cells that I am creating aren't showing up. Those lines specifically are the following:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return messages.count
//        return 5
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

//        let message = messages[indexPath.item]
//        cell.textView.text = message.text
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 80)
}
```

Comment: When and where does `observeMessages` get called?

Comment: If `observeMessages` never gets called, then `messages` never gets populated, and therefore nothing will be in the collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following delegates and data source.

To your class add `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

Then in your `viewDidLoad` add `self.collectionView?.delegate = self`and `self.collectionView?.dataSource = self`.

This tells the view controller that it’s delegate and data source methods are in its own class. 
This should solve your issue. Sorry if the formatting is off a bit in this answer. On my phone so can’t see the question as I type the answer!

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks. Just a minor change. When I added the two extensions to my class, it told me that it was redundant, so they must be in part of my already extended classes. Adding those second bits of code helped me solve the issue though! Thank You!